# How to do flat shaded polygons/geometry in SceneKit i.e. not smooth

Tags: swift, polygon, scenekit

I'm trying to make my geometry look flat and not smooth in SceneKit. As you can see in the images, the green sphere has smooth shading by default in SceneKit. What I want is the flat "look" in the other image where it says "flat".

[image: SCNSphere]
[image: SmoothVSFlat]
I don't see any options in SceneKit on how to disable this feature?
This is the code from my playground:

```
import Cocoa
import SceneKit
import QuartzCore
import XCPlayground

var sceneView = SCNView(frame:CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:300, height:300))
var scene = SCNScene()
sceneView.backgroundColor = NSColor.darkGrayColor()
sceneView.scene = scene
sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = sceneView

let g = SCNSphere(radius:1)
g.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = NSColor.greenColor()
g.firstMaterial?.litPerPixel = false
g.segmentCount = 5
let node = SCNNode(geometry:g)
node.position = SCNVector3(x:0, y:0, z:0)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)

var spin = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:"rotation")
spin.toValue = NSValue(SCNVector4:SCNVector4(x:1, y:1, z:0, w:CGFloat(2.0*M_PI)))
spin.duration = 3
spin.repeatCount = HUGE
node.addAnimation(spin, forKey:"spin")
```

Comment: The color is being interpolated between the normal vectors defined at vertices. According to the documentation for `SCNMaterial.lightingModelName`, 3 of the options interpolate, and 1 uses only ambient light. I don't think you'll be able to get the quad-shaped faces from an SCNSphere, which uses a triangulated rectangular grid (or a geodesic one), so you might also find yourself getting into the SCNGeometrySource or Model I/O business. If you go that route, you can duplicate the vertices and specify normals per face instead of per vertex. I hope there's an easier way I'm overlooking.

Comment: Ooh! This looks useful, if you have to build your own geometry: http://github.prideout.net/shapes/

Comment: In the scene editor, there's a setting I've accidentally hit, sometimes, that gives the hard edged polygons. Sorry, I don't remember if it was in materials or something to do with the object.

Comment: I actually solved this in a 3D app by tweaking the normals and then exporting / importing into SceneKit.

Answer (score 2):

It seems Apple will apply normal smoothing for you. This is more observe when SceneKit encounter a flat mesh.
Remove the smoothed normals from mesh will make it looks low polygon.

If you use ModelI/O to load 3D asset. (For test I create `MDLMesh` form `SCNGeometry`)

```
SCNGeometry* flatGeoUsingModelIO(SCNGeometry *geo){
    MDLMesh *mesh = [MDLMesh meshWithSCNGeometry:geo];
    MDLMesh *newMesh = [MDLMesh newSubdividedMesh:mesh submeshIndex:0 subdivisionLevels:0];
    [newMesh removeAttributeNamed:@"normals"];
    //Replace current vertex normals with a non-smooth one. Same result with above line
    //[newMesh addNormalsWithAttributeNamed:@"normals" creaseThreshold:1];
    SCNGeometry *flatGeo = [SCNGeometry geometryWithMDLMesh:newMesh];
    return flatGeo;
}
```

Or you are more familiar to SceneKit.

```
SCNGeometry* flatGeoUsingScnKit(SCNGeometry *geo){
    NSArray<SCNGeometrySource*> *SourceArr = geo.geometrySources;
    NSMutableArray<SCNGeometrySource*> *newSourceArr = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (SCNGeometrySource *source in SourceArr) {
        if (source.semantic != SCNGeometrySourceSemanticNormal) {
            [newSourceArr addObject:source];
        }
    }
    SCNGeometry *flatGeo = [SCNGeometry geometryWithSources:newSourceArr elements:geo.geometryElements];
    return flatGeo;
}
```

This is low polygon `SCNSphere` created from right one.

[image]

Comment: Does MDLmesh do auto triangulation? I didn't find document on it. What do we have in the vertexbuffer, it's triange or polygon?